# MySQL - multiply fields in same table, store in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Quote     Super      Factor
29        63                   [83.79]
38        61                   [81.13]
79        65                   [86.45]

47        40                   [80]
81        25                   [50]
82        35                   [70]
```

I want to take the column 'Super' and multiply it by 1.33 *IF* the 'Quote' is 29, 38, 79. If the field 'Quote' is 47, 81, 82 then multiply 'Super' by 2.

Quote is "BigInt(10)" and both 'Super' and 'Factor' have a type of "Double". The name of the table is "Quote_IDX".

Note: The numbers in '[]' are what I should end up with once this calculation is done. As you can probably tell I'm fairly new to MySQL so I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the overall problem you're trying to solve? It seems odd to have to arbitrarily multiply a few hard-coded numbers by another hard-coded number.

Comment: I was actually told to change the 'Super' numbers but not all of those will change and I wanted to be able to keep those numbers intact. I added the 'Factor' field to store the new numbers.

Comment: What does the table actually store, though? What does it do? What's the business domain? At this point I guess I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: It's on a private site where we do testing. The table in question stores their grade. All I'm doing is multiplying their grade by a given factor based on what test the student had taken. Why? Because the client wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following which uses a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement. The `SELECT` will show you the data results:

```
select quote, super, 
  case when quote in (29, 38, 79)
        then super * 1.33
      when quote  in (47, 81, 82)
        then super * 2.0
      else 0
  end factor
from Quote_IDX
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41d4e/1).  Then if you want to do an `UPDATE` of the `factor` column:

```
update Quote_IDX
set factor = (case when quote in (29, 38, 79)
                then super * 1.33
              when quote  in (47, 81, 82)
                then super * 2.0
              else 0 end)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82d38/1)

Comment: +1 for "SQL Fiddle". I just used the second half of your solution to 'fix' my data. Worked great!